# Inject already resolved instance (via constructor) in the same scope with Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

Well I think this is possible but not sure how it could be done. Here is my scenario: I have 2 services, one depends on another, like this:

```
public interface IServiceA {
    //...
}
public interface IServiceB {
    //...
}
//the actual implementation
public class ServiceA : IServiceA {
    //...
}
public class ServiceB : IServiceB {
    readonly IServiceA _serviceA;
    public ServiceB(IServiceA serviceA){
        _serviceA = serviceA;
    }
}
```

I have another class consuming both services like this:

```
public class MyConsumer {
    readonly IServiceA _serviceA;
    readonly IServiceB _serviceB;
    public MyConsumer(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB){
        _serviceA = serviceA;
        _serviceB = serviceB;
    }
}
```

So here I would like the `serviceB` to be injected with what resolved for the `serviceA` right here in this constructor of `MyConsumer`. (meaning the `serviceA` injected into `ServiceB` should be exactly the instance `serviceA` injected into `MyConsumer` - not some new different instance).
Note that: I don't want to expose `ServiceA` via `ServiceB` and just make `MyConsumer` depend on `IServiceB` only (actually `ServiceA` is the basic service while other services including `ServiceB` are just extensions, meaning there may be more services like `ServiceB` in this case)

I'm really new to Autofac and really even with Unity (I've used the most) I've never thought of this scenario before, so really I don't have any code made so far.

I hope someone here has encountered this same scenario before and could provide with me some suggestion, thanks!

**Bonus question:** what if the order of parameters (passed-in `MyConsumer` constructor) is changed? I mean does that affect the resolving order and can cause unexpected result? If possible the parameters order should not matter (because the `MyConsumer` should just care about what it need, not how the things it need are ordered).

**A larger picture of the problem**:
Some ones have suggested to use `defined scope` which is supported by autofac for some cases. However my scenario here is different and I think that it's not very convenient to force autofac to understand what I want.

The `MyConsumer` here may actually never be resolved directly (using `.Resolve` method) because it may be just a dependency of another class (which is what we call `.Resolve` for).
By using `scope convention`, I think it's the right approach but the scope in my case is different, I think it's naturally defined by the class's constructor (all dependencies injected in should be in the same scope - and each instance of a type in that scope should be a singleton - which is shared among them). Not sure why this is missing from what Autofac can provide us.

Comment: documentartion http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope

Comment: the order does not matter to the container.

Comment: [Have you looked at the `Owned<T>` relationship?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) Combining that with instance per lifetime scope registrations can be powerful.

Comment: @TravisIllig I think using Owned does not provide a flexible way both when registering and resolving. It's not very convenient, I've just tried a simple test with it and really I don't think it's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a separate solution from the other answer that hopefully addresses your concerns about special usage of the container:

```
namespace AutofacTest
{
    public interface IServiceA { }
    public interface IServiceB { }

    public class ServiceA : IServiceA
    {
    }

    public class ServiceB : IServiceB
    {
        private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;

        public ServiceB (IServiceA serviceA)
        {
            _serviceA = serviceA;
        }
    }

    public class MyConsumer
    {
        private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;
        private readonly IServiceB _serviceB;

        public MyConsumer(Func<IServiceA> serviceAFactory, Func<IServiceA, IServiceB> serviceBFactory)
        {
            _serviceA = serviceAFactory();
            _serviceB = serviceBFactory(_serviceA);
        }
    }
}
```

In this solution I'm injecting factories instead of instances and then invoking them to get the instances. One thing that's a little bit ugly about this implementation is that parameter order now DOES matter.

If you really don't want the order to matter, you could expose a setter for the `IServiceA` on the `IServiceB` interface and then replace the constructor with something like

```
public MyConsumer(Func<IServiceA> serviceAFactory, Func<IServiceB> serviceBFactory)
{
    _serviceA = serviceAFactory();
    _serviceB = serviceBFactory(_serviceA);
    _serviceB.SetServiceA(_serviceA);
}
```

Comment: this looks like a bit manual solution to me, although it is fairly creative, so I can just upvote this but it's not really a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I put together a small sample of what I think would work for your situation:

```
namespace AutofacTest
{
    public interface IServiceA { }
    public interface IServiceB { }
    public interface IMyConsumer { }

    public class ServiceA : IServiceA
    {
    }

    public class ServiceB : IServiceB
    {
        private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;

        public ServiceB (IServiceA serviceA)
        {
            _serviceA = serviceA;
        }
    }

    public class MyConsumer : IMyConsumer
    {
        private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;
        private readonly IServiceB _serviceB;

        public MyConsumer(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB)
        {
            _serviceA = serviceA;
            _serviceB = serviceB;
        }
    }

    public class AutofacInit
    {
        public IContainer BuildContainer()
        {
            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

            containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServiceB>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyConsumer>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            return containerBuilder.Build();
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            using (var container = BuildContainer())
            {
                using (var myConsumer = container.Resolve<Owned<IMyConsumer>>())
                {
                    //use myConsumer.Value
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using nested lifetime scopes (created by resolving an `Owned<IMyConsumer>`) in which only one instance of `IServiceA`, `IServiceB`, and `IMyConsumer` will exist. One thing to note is that you should always be resolving/injecting an `Owned<IMyConsumer>` and never be resolving/injecting a plain `IMyConsumer` if you take this approach, otherwise the `IServiceA` and `IServiceB` dependencies will be singletons.

This should also handle your bonus question -- nothing in this sample cares about ordering of parameters.

Comment: thank you for your answer, really I think your solution requires some special use of `Container` which does not match my usage. Your approach fairly much like what of Nkosi, which I feel a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like all you need to do is to ensure that all of them - `MyConsumer`, `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` (and other "extensions" as you call them) - are registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`. As long as they are resolved from the same scope all of them will be "singletons" for that scope. Have you tried it in your code? If you're having some problem with this approach then you need to explicitly say it in your question because it is pretty hard to figure out what your real problem is. Personally I think that the problem is not the autofac itself or fitting your services in it, it's just lack of familiarity with the new DI container - which is quite natural thing, every new technology has its learning curve. Just keep trying, keep experimenting, and you'll get it done. Autofac is very powerful DI container, so I'm pretty sure it can do what you want.